# How to batch process a series of video files with powershell and other-transcode/ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

**TL;DR**

What did I do wrong in the following PowerShell-Script? It does not work as expected.

---

I am recording some of my lectures in my university with a photo camera. This works pretty well although I have to split the single lecture into three to four parts because the camera can only record 29 minutes of video in one take. I know that this is a common issue related to some licensensing problem that most photo cameras simply don't have the right license to record longer videos. But it confronts me with the problem that I later have to edit the files together after I did some post processing on them.

With the camera I produce up to four video files with sizes around 3.5 GB which is way to big in order to be of any use because our IT department understandably doesn't want to host so much data, as I produce around 22 GB of video material each week.

Some time ago I came across a very useful tool called "[other-video-transcoding](https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding)" by Don Melton over on GitHub, written in ruby, that allows me to compress the files to a reasonable file size without any visual loss. In addition I crop the videos to remove the part of each frame that is neither the board nor a place where my professor stands in order to decrease the filesize even further and do some privacy protection by cutting out most of the students.

As the tools are accessable via the command line, it is relatively easy to configure and does not cost additional computational power to render a nice gui, so I can edit one of the 29 minute clips in less than 10 minutes.

Now I wanted to optimize my workflow by writing a PowerShell script that only takes the parameters what to crop and which files to work on and then does the rest on its own so I can just start the script and then do something else while my laptop renders the new files.

So far I have the following:

```ps
$video_path = Get-ChildItem ..\ -Directory | findstr "SoSe"

Get-ChildItem $video_path -name | findstr ".MP4" | Out-File temp.txt -Append 
Get-Content temp.txt | ForEach-Object {"file " + $_} >> .\files.txt

Get-ChildItem $video_path |
Foreach-Object {
other-transcode --hevc --mp4 --target 3000 --crop 1920:780:0:0 $_.FullName
}

#other-transcode --hevc --mp4 --crop 1920:720:60:0 ..\SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v14_RAW\
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy merged.mp4
Remove-Item .\temp.txt
```

but it does not quite do what I it expect to do.
This is my file system:

```
sciebo/
└── SoSe22_Theo1_videos/
    ├── SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v16/
    │   ├── SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v16_KOMPR/
    │   │   ├── C0001.mp4
    │   │   ├── C0002.mp4
    │   │   ├── C0003.mp4
    │   │   ├── C0004.mp4
    │   │   ├── temp.txt
    │   │   ├── files.txt
    │   │   └── merged.mp4
    │   └── SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v16_RAW/
    │       ├── C0001.mp4
    │       ├── C0002.mp4
    │       ├── C0003.mp4
    │       └── C0004.mp4
    └── SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v17/
        ├── SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v17_KOMPR
        └── SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v17_RAW/
            ├── C0006.mp4
            ├── C0007.mp4
            ├── C0008.mp4
            └── C0009.mp4
```

where the 16th lecture is already processed and the 17th is not. I always have the raw video data in the folders ending on `RAW` and the edited/compressed output files in the one ending on `KOMPR`. Note that the video files in the `KOMPR` folder are the output files of the `other-transcode` tool.

The real work happens in the line where it says

```ps
other-transcode --hevc --mp4 --target 3000 --crop 1920:780:0:0 $_.FullName
```

and in the line

```ps
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy merged.mp4
```

where I concat the output files into the final version I can upload to our online learning platform.
What is wrong with my script? In the end I'd like to pass the `--crop` parameter just to my script, but that is not the primary problem.

---

A little information on the transcoding script so you don't have to look into the documentation: 
As the last argument the tool takes the location of the video files to work on, be it relative or absolute file paths. The output is placed in the folder the script is called in, so if I cd into one of the `KOMPR` directories and then call

```ps
other-transcode --mp4 ../SoSe22_Theo1_videos_v16_RAW/C0001.mp4
```

a new file `C0001.mp4` is created in the `KOMPR` directory and the transcoded video and old audio are written to that new video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Get-ChildItem to get the 'SoSe*_RAW' folders first and loop through these.
On each iteration, check if there is a 'SoSe*_KOMPR' folder next to it and if it already has a 'merged.mp4 file'.
If that is the case, then skip processing the folder and proceed with the next one.

Try

```
$allVideos = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\sciebo' -Filter 'SoSe*_RAW' -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $mergedPath = $_.FullName -replace '_[a-z]+$', '_KOMPR'
    $mergedFile = Join-Path -Path $mergedPath -ChildPath 'merged.mp4'
    if (Test-Path -Path $mergedFile -PathType Leaf) {
        # already processed
        continue  # skip this and proceed with the next folder
    }
    # convert each file in the folder
    $mp4Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.mp4' -File | Sort-Object {[int]$_.BaseName.Substring(1)}
    if (@($mp4Files).Count) {
        # make sure there is a 'SoSe*_KOMPR' folder
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $mergedPath -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $mergedPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        # convert the videos into the 'SoSe*_KOMPR'
        $transcoded = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
        foreach ($video in $mp4Files) {
            # copy the file to the 'SoSe*_KOMPR' first and transcode there
            $copy = $video | Copy-Item -Destination $mergedPath -PassThru
            other-transcode --hevc --mp4 --target 3000 --crop 1920:780:0:0 $copy.FullName
            # add a string for the files.txt
            $transcoded.Add(('file {0}' -f $copy.FullName))
        }
        # create a files.txt file with all converted filenames in it
        $fileList = Join-Path -Path $mergedPath -ChildPath 'files.txt'
        $transcoded | Set-Content -Path $fileList
        # then combine all the videos into merged.mp4
        ffmpeg -f concat -i $fileList -c copy $mergedFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very promising. I can't say that I understand everything of what you wrote there as I am very new to PowerShell and this is basically my first attempt on writing a script, normally I just type every command on it's own. I have two further questions: Why do you want to copy the files to the destination folder first? And second, the transcoding tool always outputs into the directory that it is called in, there is no option to tell it where to send the output. Do you think that will work?

Comment: And if you have some time, I would be very happy if you could explain some more how your code will operate? The comments are already very helpful, but I would love to know what exactly each step does so that I can learn to solve such problems on my own the next time.

Comment: @DarkDiamond Because I'm not familiar with the tool you use for transcoding the files, I tried finding documentation and for all I could find, it doesn't have an option to specify a source and a different output filename. So from that, I gather it transcodes the file in-place. That's why I copy the original away first and work on that, safegarding the original in the *_RAW folder.
As for further explanation, I use a `Sort-Object` with a calculated property, being the file's BaseName (name without extension) and take whatever follows the first character, cast as integer number.

Comment: ...so we eventually merge these files in the correct order.
The transcoded file full path names are then added to a List object (`$transcoded`) prefixed with `'file '` to use for the ffmpeg input file

Comment: Ok, I added some information on how the transcoding tool works, it is not that well documented without installing it and calling the man pages. In the end, you cd into the directory you want to have the output files to be in and call it there with the video file you want transcoded as the last argument.