# Powershell call a script from another scipt as if in a different folder

Tags: powershell, file-io

I use the video transcoding tools made by Don Melton over on [GitHub](https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding) to compress self filmed videos. Now I would like to automate this task by using a PowerShell script to loop over the contents of a folder as input arguments for the tool and have the output put into a seperate folder. My problem is that the tool is written in a way that it has no option to provide an output location, instead it always places the output files in the directory where it is called in. So when I `cd` into an "output" directory "next to" the one where my input files are, I then can call

```ps
other-transcode ../input/file.mp4
```

and the output file of the same name as the input file will be placed in the output directory.

Now when I want to use the command in a script, how do I tell PowerShell to run the command as if it was typed manually into a shell that was in the output directory at the moment?

---

For context, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72518291/14435572) is my end goal, but I think it is easier to split the complicated question into multiple ones.

Comment: `Set-Location path\to\output\directory; [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD; other-transcode ...`; Setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to the current location will ensure that ruby uses the current location as it's working directory path when subsequently invoked.

Comment: Good point about `Set-Location`, @Mathias, but note that the need to set `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` / specify _full_ paths only applies to _in-process_ API calls; in calls to external programs / scripting engines, PowerShell always sets the child process' working directory to the current file-system location.